# Laravel 5.2 Showing a table using a .blade view

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

I have my DB, already migrated everything, my code can record new entries in my table when required, and so on.

I have a table with the contents of: 'id', 'name', 'lastname', 'email', 'phone', 'address'.

What I want is, when you hit the submit button, you'll be redirected to a new 'view.blade.php' where you can see all of the DB's entries, including the most recent. BUT I don't know how to develop this code to make it work.

I need help with that, please.
Thank you.

Comment: when you hit submit button are you sending it to a controller , saving details to db and then returning view.blade.php?

Comment: Watch this tutorial: it's gold. https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-5-fundamentals

Comment: Yes, Sapnesh. 

I hit submit, send the data to my DB and then I get redirected to the view.blade.php.

But this blade is blank, there is nothing in it. I want to show my table here.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In your controller function do this right after you store a new record to table.
assuming your model name is `User`

**fetch all user records from User model,**

```
$users =  App\User::all();
```

**pass this users variable to view**(assuming your `view.blade.php` is in `resources/views` folder)

```
return View::make('view', compact('users'));
```

**and then in your view.blade.php** you can do something like this to display all user records.

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th> id</th>
            <th> name</th>
            <th> last name  </th>
            <th> email </th>
            <th> phone</th>
            <th> adddress </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
         @foreach($users as $user)
          <tr>
              <td> {{$user->id}} </td>
              <td> {{$user->name}} </td>
              <td> {{$user->last_name}} </td>
              <td> {{$user->email}} </td>
              <td> {{$user->phone}} </td>
              <td> {{$user->address}} </td>
          </tr>
         @endforeach
   </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: You need to always check if count of users is greater than 0 before starting foereach!

Comment: Yes, Mihir. Since my table already had some info (I was viewing it in a separate program, DBeaver), I overlooked it, but that's a good input. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

//form.blade.php

```
<form method="post" action="{{ route('submitForm') }}">
    {!! csrf_field() !!}
    <input type="text" name="name"/>
    <input type="text" name="last_name"/>
    <input type="text" name="email"/>
    <input type="text" name="phone"/>
    <input type="text" name="address"/>
</form>

<?php
//app/Http/controllers/YourController.php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\User;

//user is your eloquent model

class YourController extends Controller
{

    //show user form
    public function showForm()
    {
        return view('form');
    }

    //post url for submit form
    public function submitForm(Request $request){

        $this->validate($request, [
            'name' => 'required|min:2|max:30',
            'lastname' => 'required|min:2|max:30',
            'email' => 'required',
            'phone' => 'required',
            'address' => 'required'
        ]);

        $user = new User();
        $user->name = $request->name; 
        $user->lastname = $request->lastname; 
        $user->email = $request->email; 
        $user->phone = $request->phone; 
        $user->address = $request->address;
        try{
            $user->save();

            return redirect()->route('showAllusers')->with('success', "User was successfully created..!");
        }
        catch(Exception $e){
            return redirect()->back()->with('error', "Could not save the user!");
        }
        return redirect()->back()->with('error', "Error Occured, please try again!");

    }

    // after form submit, redirect to this page where all users will be showcased
    public function showAllusers()
    {
        $users = User::all();

        return view('allusers', compact('users'));
    }

}
?>
```

//allusers.blade.php

```
@if($users->count > 0)
  <table>
      <thead>
          <tr>
              <th> id</th>
              <th> name</th>
              <th> last name  </th>
              <th> email </th>
              <th> phone</th>
              <th> adddress </th>
          </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
           @foreach($users as $user)
            <tr>
                <td> {{$user->id}} </td>
                <td> {{$user->name}} </td>
                <td> {{$user->last_name}} </td>
                <td> {{$user->email}} </td>
                <td> {{$user->phone}} </td>
                <td> {{$user->address}} </td>
            </tr>
           @endforeach
     </tbody>
  </table>
@else
  <p> No users found..</p>
@endif
```

//routes.php

```
<?php 
Route::get('/showForm', 'YourController@index')->name('showForm');
Route::post('/submitForm', 'YourController@index')->name('submitForm');
Route::get('/showAllusers', 'YourController@index')->name('showAllusers');

?>
```

Comment: IT WORKS! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I should write this code for display all `users` table data :

```
//Function for store users data
public fucntion store(Request $request){
    $insertData = DB::table('users')->insert(array(
        'name'=>$request->name,
        'lastname'=>$request->lastname,
        'email'=>$request->email,
        'phone'=>$request->phone,
        'address'=>$request->address
    ));
    return Redirect::to('/view')
}
//fucntion for display users data
public fucntion view(){
    $rsltUsers = User::get();
    return view('view', compact('rsltUsers'));
}
```

**view.blade.php**

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Last Name</th>
            <th>Email</th>
            <th>Phone</th>
            <th>Address</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    @foreach($rsltUsers as $rsltUser)
        <td>{!! $rsltUser->name !!}</td>
        <td>{!! $rsltUser->lastname !!}</td>
        <td>{!! $rsltUser->email !!}</td>
        <td>{!! $rsltUser->phone !!}</td>
        <td>{!! $rsltUser->address !!}</td>
    @endforeach
    </tbody>
</table>
```